# Como somar automaticamente duas colunas de duas tabelas diferentes e realizar insert em outra tabela no MySQL?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

Estou iniciando o trabalho com banco de dados e gostaria de realizar uma ação inteligente no banco.

Tenho duas tabelas que guardam informações de sensores diferentes, cada uma delas com suas respectivas colunas.

Eu gostaria de pegar uma coluna de cada tabela (de minha escolha) e realizar uma soma de ambas, como o select abaixo:

```
SELECT (SELECT COLUNA1_T1 FROM T1) + (SELECT COLUNA1_T2 FROM T2) as COLUNA1_T3
```

O meu resultado em COLUNA1_T3 seria a soma dos primeiros de uma linha das colunas, por exemplo.

Essa ação poderia ser rodada através de uma trigger após a inserção de algum dado nas tabelas T1 e T2 e assim somar os dados da linha adicionada.

Gostaria de alguma sugestão de como isso pode ser realizado.

Obrigado.

Comment: Você quer executar isso direto numa query no banco ou vai usar algo pra isso? (algum site, programa...)

Comment: Eu vou usar direto no banco, para que ele controle as entradas.

Answer (score 2):

Qual a finalidade se os registros das tabelas não tem uma relação entre si?

Para relacionar as 2 tabelas, elas têm que ter um campo chave em comum para você declarar no `INNER JOIN` outro qualquer JOIN.

Desta forma, você conseguirá fazer a soma algo tipo:

```
SELECT T1.COLUNA1_T1 + T2.COLUNA1_T2 as COLUNA1_T3 FROM T1 INNER JOIN T1 ON T1.CHAVE = T2.CHAVE
```

Comment: A unica relação que as mesmas carregam são em questão ao identificador de quem está inserindo a informação onde tecnicamente seriam inseridas ambas ao mesmo tempo, mesmo sendo informações diferentes.

Comment: Em "ON T1.CHAVE = T2.CHAVE" o chave não pode ser o Id de inserção de cada uma?

Answer (score 1):

Minimizei meu problema. Eu juntei as duas tabelas, afinal apenas uma coluna alternava e as mesmas eram inseridas automaticamente. Agora criei uma trigger no banco para gerar a soma automaticamente:

```
set new.T3 = (new.T1 + new.T2)
```

Obrigado pela resposta.